# Efficient algorithm for finding harmonic mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Is there a fast algorithm for calculating a harmonic mean of numbers? Not just summing all of the values in the denominator. How can we speed up this? In python3

Comment: you can use scipy libary https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.hmean.html

Comment: @manzet i know, but i want implement without any additional libraries

Comment: @manzet is it even possible?

Comment: Possibly, definitely. Python it turing complete ;) But since Pyhton is a rather slow language I would recommend to use a libary like scipy when it comes to speed, because it is written in C and just wrapped with python

Comment: The repeated operations for harmonic mean (reciprocal and sum) are cheap, and insignificant compared to the overhead of iterating through a plain python list and extracting floats. If you don't want to use numpy, it's not practically possible without reinventing large parts of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

```
    from statistics import harmonic_mean

    print(harmonic_mean([1, 4, 4]) # prints 2.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The naive approach would be O(n).

```
numbers = [3, 2, 6, 5, 1, 8] # example numbers

add = 0
for i in numbers:
    add += 1/i

harmonic_mean = len(numbers)/add
```

Comment: How does this answer `How can we speed up [finding harmonic mean to faster than just summing all of the values in the denominator]`?